# responsive pyramid alignment of blocks

Tags: javascript, html, css

Got stuck on next issue. I need to make a responsive layout of blocks, which would always align themselves as upside-down pyramid without size loss. Is it possible to achieve with some native ways? Without any libraries and frameworks? I tried to acheive that with flexbox, but I failed, because on lower breakpoints, alignment does not fit my requirements. Would be grateful for any advise.

```css
.pyramid__container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.pyramid__item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 8px;
  background: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.pyramid__item-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}  

@media screen and (min-width:960px) {
    .pyramid__item-container {
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="pyramid__container">
  <div class="pyramid__item-container">
    <div class="pyramid__item item-1"></div>
    <div class="pyramid__item item-2"></div>
    <div class="pyramid__item item-3"></div>
    <div class="pyramid__item item-4"></div>
    <div class="pyramid__item item-5"></div>
    <div class="pyramid__item item-6"></div>
    <div class="pyramid__item item-7"></div>
    <div class="pyramid__item item-8"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="pyramid__item-container">
    <div class="pyramid__item item-9"></div>
    <div class="pyramid__item item-10"></div>
    <div class="pyramid__item item-11"></div>
    <div class="pyramid__item item-12"></div>
    <div class="pyramid__item item-13"></div>
    <div class="pyramid__item item-14"></div>
    <div class="pyramid__item item-15"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="pyramid__item-container">
    <div class="pyramid__item item-16"></div>
    <div class="pyramid__item item-17"></div>
    <div class="pyramid__item item-18"></div>
    <div class="pyramid__item item-19"></div>
    <div class="pyramid__item item-20"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what should be the expected result?

Comment: *because on lower breakpoints, alignment does not fit my requirements* --> how you want it to behave on lower breakpoints?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderanlovestrees it should always remain a pyramid.

Comment: @TemaniAfif it should always remain a pyramid

Comment: You want pyramid inside each container or somehow ignore the containers and pyramid out individual blocks together? If it's the first, than you can try `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;`

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate it using inline-block, float and shape-outside. The values are a bit tricky to adjust and they all need to percetange to keep the same layout:

```css
.box {
  font-size: 0; /* remove empty spaces */
  text-align:center;
}
.box  div {
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0.5%;
  font-size: initial; /* reset the font-size */
}
/* maintain a fixed ratio for divs */
.box div::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 40%;
}
/**/

.box i{
  width:50%; 
}
.box i:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
}
  
.box  i:last-of-type {
  float:right;
  shape-outside:linear-gradient(to bottom right,#0000 50%,#000 0);
}
.box i:first-of-type {
  float:left;
  shape-outside:linear-gradient(to bottom left,#0000 50%,#000 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
  </div>
```

For the opposite pyramid you simply adjust both gradients (change bottom with top) and reduce the width of the float elements slightly

```css
.box {
  font-size: 0; /* remove empty spaces */
  text-align:center;
}
.box  div {
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0.5%;
  font-size: initial; /* reset the font-size */
}
/* maintain a fixed ratio for divs */
.box div::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 40%;
}
/**/

.box i{
  width:40%; 
}
.box i:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
}
  
.box  i:last-of-type {
  float:right;
  shape-outside:linear-gradient(to top right,#0000 50%,#000 0);
}
.box i:first-of-type {
  float:left;
  shape-outside:linear-gradient(to top left,#0000 50%,#000 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this option. Is it somehow possible to achieve without losing it's actual size? As there would be text content inside these blocks, and it would be not readable if it would be changing it's actual size.